# Join the line above the current line

Tags: key-bindings, join

I often use `J` to join the current line with the one below:

```
J                       Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines.
                        Remove the indent and insert up to two spaces (see
                        below).  Fails when on the last line of the buffer.
                        If [count] is too big it is reduce to the number of
                        lines available.
```

**Is there a shortcut key for joining the current line with the line *above*?**

Needless to say, `kJ` does the trick; I just wonder if there's a built-in shortcut for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm almost sure there is no such mapping. As you wrote, one can use <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. But if you aren't using <kbd>K</kbd>, you can remap it to `kJ`:

```
nnoremap K kJ
```